# How to concat haml variable with img src string

Tags: css, haml

I have haml loop with CSS class `thumbnail`, inside for loop I just wanna concat src string with for loop index.

```
%li.slide
   %img.thumbnail{src=> 'string'i}
```

Comment: this question nothing to do with CSS, remove the wrong tag css, and your hall syntax seems so wrong, variable name should start with #

Comment: `I just wanna concat src string with for loop index` -- What for loop? What are you supposed to be looping over?  I presume this is a ruby (rails?) application; is there any other code we should know about? What problem are you actually trying to solve? Context, context, context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `haml` syntax is wrong, check this simple loop with `img` src string injection.

```
- (1..3).each do |i|
  %li.sld
    %img.thumbnail{:src => "string#{i}"}
```

you have missed `:` and wrong variable syntax `i` it should be `#{i}`.

try this way and comment me.

Comment: Is it ok if I use single quotes for string?